Fuzzy search logic using JpaSpecificationExecutor
I have a column c1 (varchar(400)) in table t1 in MYSql database. This column can contain data in plain text and json format like "abcd","12345.6",{"key1":"value1"},{"key1":"value1","key2","value2"} etc. I want to implement a fuzzy search logic in this column. User can search using "34", "cd",{"key1":"value1"}, "value1" etc. User can perform serch by providing a full or partial value. User can provide the entire json value or partial value.
I am currently doing a search on multiple columns using the JpaSpecificationExecutor so in this perticular column search i have added criteriaBuilder.like("c1","%" + value + "%"). Performance is really slow by using like operator. Problem here is user can pass the values in text and json format both and it is doing a full table scan as i am using "%value%".
Can you suggest some approach i can use to implement a fuzzy search in spring data jpa? Any suggestion is welcome which migh have worked for you in past experiences. i will try those.
I am using spring-data-jpa 2.3.3 version and mysql 5.7.22 version.

You can't really index for completely random searches within a column's value using a traditional relational database therefore such searches will always be slow. Either you live with this restriction or use vector database to store text embedsings and search using those.

But I can't change db just for this. Is there any technique I can use to at least optimize it? What restrictions should I keep for the search values?

The way to optimise this search is to move the json document into tables and columns as a normal  relational database structure and forget json.  Mysql is a relational database. It has very limited capabilities to work with json.

The problem i have is, this column is actually the id from multiple data sources. so it is having string and json format both. I  am trying to manage a partial search on this data. Suppose the data is "abcd123xx",  {"key1":"xyz123abc"} or {"key1":"abc","key2":"4441234"} and if i will try to search 123 as search value then all 3 should match. Means i will try to search the text if it is plain data or search in value part if it is in json format. Is there any way to achieve this with a better performance in jpa?

This structure can be mapped to tables. If you keep this data as json, you have to accept that searching it comes with a high cost.

Even with normalized tables, you can't index for arbitrary queries or "fuzzy" queries. Indexing helps specific queries. You can't optimize for unknown criteria.

It's like if you're designing a telephone book, and you are trying to decide whether to sort the entries by last name, or sort them by first name, or sort them by phone number. You ask the user how they want to look up entries in the phone book. The user says, "I don't know, I might search any way. Or I might search on partial names." You can't make a telephone book based on that.
